# How to add a new field with a formula to the pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I create a pivot table:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Sheets("Working").UsedRange).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="HDPivotTable", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
ActiveSheet.Name = "HD Pivot"

ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").AddFields RowFields:="Location Code"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotFields("h,d,x").Orientation = xlDataField


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotFields("h,d,x")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField

    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        ' Filter out columns that are not "D" or "H"
        If .PivotItems(i) <> "D" And .PivotItems(i) <> "H" Then
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next      

End With
```

So the resulting table looks like this:

[image]

I need to add a new column "T/F" after Grand Total that would have TRUE if values in columns "D" and "H" are equal, and FALSE otherwise. I have it in red and highlighted. I cannot make it work, whatever I tried. I am not an expert in VBA or Excel, so I only could try whatever I found on internet.

Comment: You only want/need to add a fiel to the pivot?? Or can you put a formula just next to the pivot???If you don't care about formats, it could be do it whit no pain.

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal It doesn't have to be in the pivot, but the very worksheet is added when the pivot is created (the pivot is created "in a new workwheet").

Comment: Please checkout the edit #3 in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a `1` if `TRUE` or `0` if is `FALSE`.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").CalculatedFields.Add "Compare", "=Monto ='D/Monto'", True
    'Where:
    'Compare : Is the name of the field (you use "T/F")
    '"=Monto = 'D/Monto'" : Is the comparison of fields you want in your case would be
    '"=D = H" <== that way
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("HDPivotTable").PivotFields("Compare").Orientation = xlDataField
    'Here you add the field to the pivot
```

**Edit #1**
Note this: In the first line you add a field, and since can not be two fields with the same name, if you run the macro twice, you will get an error in the first line.

If you, already create the field ("Compare", using my example), you only need to add the fiel to the `xlDataField`.

**Edit 2**

Just decide to edit this questions...

```
Sub addComp()

    Dim r 'to store the last row
    Dim c 'to store the last column

    c = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Grand Total", Range("A3").EntireRow, 0)
        'to find the last column of the pivot
        'in your case would be "Grand Total"
        'if add 1 to c, we get the column next to the pivot
        '
        'In my example, I use my own header, but you can use yours.
        'In your question you use "Grand total", i change it.
        '
        'And that is why you get and error, becuase MATCH was  looking for "Sum of D/Monto",
        'not "Grand total"
    r = Range(Cells(3, c), Cells(3, c)).End(xlDown).Row
        'here I use the 3th row because, in my case my pivot is in the
        '3th row, but you can use the row you want/need
        'that range/row, is the reference that use the pivot to set its position
        'inside the worksheet.
        'And using that row as a reference, whith the code
        'r = Range(Cells(3, c), Cells(3, c)).End(xlDown).Row I just find the last row down
        'no matter how many rows be. Is like, to manually got to the "Grand total" header,
        'press Shift+DownArrow, and you will go to the last row, the code above do the very same.
        '
        'To find the las row of the pivot

    Range(Cells(3, c + 1), Cells(3, c + 1)).Value = "T/F"
        'Here adds the name of our field
    Range(Cells(4, c + 1), Cells(r - 1, c + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]=RC[-1]"
        'Here add the TRUE/FALSE to all the cells in the next column of the pivot.
        'I don't use the formula with the Grand total row, but if you want,
        'just remove the " - 1" next to r in the second Cells
End Sub
```

**Edit #3**

```
Sub addComp()
    Dim r 'to store the last row
    Dim c 'to store the last column
    c = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Grand Total", Range("A2").EntireRow, 0)
    r = Range(Cells(2, c), Cells(2, c)).End(xlDown).Row
    Range(Cells(2, c + 1), Cells(2, c + 1)).Value = "T/F"
    Range(Cells(3, c + 1), Cells(r - 1, c + 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]=RC[-1]"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Elbert. I tried it, and got an error on the second line: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class.

Comment: You got the error, (may be) because, you don't change the name of the field, "Compare" to the name you use. In you question you use "T/F". Use the right name and tell me if you need some improvement.

Comment: Well, I have no errors... please, re-check the macro, and my edit #1. I will post another answer for you... I got your back Bro!

Comment: Hmm, I see you use row 3, but it may be not just one row, as in this particular example, it may be any number of rows. Also I don't understand what "Sum of D/Monto" is. And I get the following error: Unable to get the Match property of the Worksheet function class.

Comment: Please the edit on **Edit #2** and read the comments... **MATCH** gives you and error because did not find anything, you need to set your header.

Comment: And not using just row 3, I'm using row 3 as a reference, to find the last row and put the formulas inside that range,  next to the pivot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103511/discussion-between-elbert-villarreal-and-david-shochet).

Comment: I used your code. For some reason, instead of comparing B3 to C3 (i.e. "D" to "H") it compares C3 to D3 (i.e. "H" to "Grand Total")...